# Can I use cookies authentication with Java high level rest client elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rest-client

Ive been searching for a way to use Java High Level Rest Client Elasticsearch with **cookies authentication**. The documentation says that they have username and password authentication, in the Low Level Rest Client which can be passed to the high level, and other authentication forms (API key and token service). Is it possible to pass the cookie in the header? Apologies if it is a dumb question, Im new with ES.

Thanks!